# How to identify <img> tag in an array data in smarty template?

Tags: php, foreach, smarty, associative-array

Following is the code snippet from smarty template. 
Actually there is an associative array and we are showing it's values in smarty template.
One such element of an associative array is `$ans.answer_text` and I've to check whether there is any `<img>` tag present in the content(value), if the `<img>` tag is present I've to do some logic and if it doesn't I've to do some other logic. 
But the main issue I'm facing is how to check the presence of `<img>` tag within the array element data? 
Please help me out to resolve this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

```
<tr valign="top">
    {foreach from=$qstn_ans.answer item=ans key=ans_no}
         <td valign="top" valign="top">
         {if $ans.answer_is_right==1}{assign var='correct_ans' value=$ans_no+1}{/if}
         <b>{$ans_no+1}.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
         {if $ans.answer_text!=''}{$ans.answer_text}{/if}
         <br />
         {if $ans.answer_file!=''}<img src="{$ans_thumb_img_path}{$ans.answer_id}_{$ans.answer_file}" />{/if}
         </td>
    {/foreach}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of usage defeats the purpose of using a temple engine. Ideally you should do these checks in the controller.

I would do it in the following way:

```
$qstn_ans = array();
// PHP Controller
foreach ($qstn_ans as $key => $value) {
    $imgPath = ''; // generate the name here
    $qstn_ans[$key]['hasImage'] = (file_exists($imgPath))?1:0;
}

// Template file
{if $ans.hasImage}<img src="<!-- insert image here -->" />{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using {html_image}?

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.html.image.tpl